# How to create subfolders in S3 bucket using cloudformation aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, cicd

I am creating a CICD pipeline and stuck on how to  create multiple subfolders in a S3 bucket in AWS using cloudformation YAML file? If yes then please suggest any example or document will be helpful.

If no, Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Example code snippet of cfn-s3.yml file.

**main bucket = test** (is created in below code), **how to create subfolder1 and subfolder2 in it.**

```
Resources:
  myS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName : Test1
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
```

Comment: Don't create the 'folders' unless you have a very specific use case for them (and you understand what S3 'folders' actually are). You almost certainly do not need them and should not create them.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use AWS CloudFormation to create content *inside* of Amazon S3 buckets.

The closest option is to create an [AWS Lambda-backed custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html), which will execute a Lambda function as part of the stack deployment. It is a rather complex way of doing things, best avoided if possible.

By the way, **you don't actually need to create subfolders** in Amazon S3 buckets. You can simply store objects in a given path and the folder will 'magically' appear because folders don't really exist in S3 buckets.